# Trying to connect a local postgresql database from node js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ionic-framework, connection, local

When I try to make a post request at first I was getting role "username" doesn't exist. Then I created a role named "username" and granted it permissions. 
Now the error I'm getting is :

> database "username" does not exist.

[connection informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olz1R.png)

```
DATABASE_URL = postgres://postgres:1234@localhost:5432/mydb
```

> error: database "AGT" does not exist
>    at Connection.parseE (C:\Users\AKT\Desktop\worldenglish\worldenglish\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:539:11)
>       at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Users\AKT\Desktop\worldenglish\worldenglish\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:366:17)
>       at Socket. (C:\Users\AKT\Desktop\worldenglish\worldenglish\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:105:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:189:7)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)

```js
//this is the node.js part
    app.post('/authOgretmen', function (request, response) {
      pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function (error, client, done) {
        if(error) {
          console.log('wtf');
          response.send(error);
          throw error;
        }
        client.query('SELECT id,yetkiderecesi from ogretmenler where email = $1 and sifre = $2', [request.body.email, request.body.sifre], function (error, result) {
          console.log("girdi");
          if (error) {
            console.log("bb");
            response.send(error.message);
            done();
          }
          else {
            console.log("true");
            response.json(result.rows[0]);
            done();
          }
        })
      if(error) {
        response.send(error);
      }
      })
    });

//this is the ionic part
    karsilastirOgretmen(){
          this.http.post(this.url,{
          "email": this.email,
          "sifre": this.sifre
          })
          .subscribe(response => {
          this.id = response.json().id;
          this.yetkiderecesi=response.json()['yetkiderecesi'];
          this.navigateToOgretmenProfil();   
        });
      }
```

Comment: Please add your code and not just some incomplete pseudo-code.

Comment: Your error message indicates that `pg` is trying to connect to an `AGT` database rather than the one you specified in the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. If no database is specified in the connection string, Postgres will try to connect to a 'home' database for the user. Are you sure that `process.env.DATABASE_URL` has the correct value?

Comment: most of the examples show that this is the correct way to write connection url. But it doesnt work for me.I'm not sure if it's correct or not.

Comment: it was seaching the db named "AGT" coz my pc's name is AGT. So i created a db called AGT and it worked but it's not a good solution. :D I still need to learn how to connect properly...